# I can't access mobile internet with google

Tags: flutter, google-signin, google-account

I didn't use firebase in my mobile app project. I logged in with google with API key from my google cloud account. my app works as apk but when play console is installed, google login doesn't work

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merhaba Nurullah, you might need to add the SHA-1 & the SHA-256 keys that you can find on your app's console to your custom authentication system.

You will find these keys in Google Play Console -> Choose your app -> Setup -> App Integrity -> App Signing